# properly handle the try {} catch {}

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I'm making an app, but I need a little help. In practice on the oncreate of the activity I have this code:

```
try{

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    check = extras.getInt("checkpoint1");

}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){

    check = 0;

}
```

in the oncreate you try to get the value of a variable check, from the another activity, if the try is not successful this variable must be set to zero. But the code as it is written now gives me error. Could you help me?

Your help give me all the same error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(3028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(3028): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.BisMagdev.notesRainbow/it.BisMagdev.notesRainbow.livello4}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at it.BisMagdev.notesRainbow.livello4.onCreate(livello4.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime(3028):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: getIntent() returns the intent that started the activity.
The intent that started the activity MAY have a Bundle of extras associated with it.
getIntent().getExtras(); <-- may return null (which is exactly what it says in the api documentation)
so 
if (null != getIntent().getExtras()){
 // Then you have extras
} else {
 // Otherwise you dont have any extras...
}

Comment: so I can try this way: Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     if (extras == null ){
     
      bubu = 0;
     }else{
      bubu = extras.getInt("checkpoint1");
     }

Comment: yes, but this code is probably less error prone...
    Int bubu = DEFAULT_BUBU_VALUE; // where DEFAULT_BUBU_VALUE is zero or some non-zero default
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (null != extras){
        bubu = extras.getInt("checkpoint1", DEFAULT_BUBU_VALUE);
    }

calling getInt("checkpoint1"); will result in zero being returned by default...

Answer (score 3):

You can set default return value, no need for try-catch:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
check = extras.getInt("checkpoint1", 0);
```

Also, `getInt` doesn't  throw `NumberFormatException` so you can't catch that exception...

Answer (score 0):

I **don't think these statements need try/catch block**... so remove them and try..

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
check = extras.getInt("checkpoint1");
```

You can however check the value of `"checkpoint1"` before assigning it to the `check` variable.

```
if ((extras.getInt("checkpoint1"))!=0){

        check = extras.getInt("checkpoint1");

 }
  else{

         check = 0;
 }
```

Comment: getInt("checkpoint1") is the same as getInt("checkpoint1", 0), ie getInt has a zero default return value

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

```
if getIntent().hasExtra("checkpoint") { // this checks for the extra...
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (null != getIntent().getExtras()){
        check = extras.getInt("checkpoint", defaultValue); // where default is non zero
        check = extras.getInt("checkpoint"); // will be zero by default if checkpoint is not found
    } else {
        // There are no extras associated with this intent
    }
} else {
    // checkpoint not contained in the extras...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is at line 60 in livello4.java? I suspect the bundle returned by getExtras() is null.

Answer (score 0):

You catch numberformatexception but you get a nullpointer exception. You have to catch the nullpointer exception too or you simply catch Exception. That means when somthing goes wrong whatever it was you can set your variable to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change NumberFormatException in Throwable so you are sure you catch NullPointerException too.